# Xamarin Forms with UWP Refresh causes value to disappear

Tags: xaml, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I have a Xamarin Forms application using Android and UWP.  Everything works fine under Android but under UWP I have a problem when I want to modify some values displayed on the screen.

Here is my (simplified) ViewModel (using Fody.PropertyChanged) :

```
public class SalesViewModel : BaseAppViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<SaleModel> Sales { get; set; } 
        = new ObservableCollection<SaleModel>();

    [DoNotNotify]
    public ICommand AddQuantityCommand => new Command<SaleModel>(item =>
    {
        item.Quantity += 1;
    });
}
```

The BaseAppViewModel implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for Fody.PropertyChanged

The (simplified) SaleModel class:

```
public class SaleModel  : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public double Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

And the (part of the) XAML which display the list of SaleModel's

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Sales, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSale, Mode=TwoWay}">   
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <ViewCell.View>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="arrow.png">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.AddQuantityCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=SalesPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
          </Image>

          <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Quantity, Mode=OneWay}" 
        </Grid>
      </ViewCell.View>
     </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

When clicking on the Image, the quantity is incremented but the value disappear from the screen under UWP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code and reproduced your issue. And I written the following `ViewCell` replace yours. Please try to modify your `ViewCell`.

```
<ViewCell>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee"
    Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="time.jpg" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" >
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding AddQuantityCommand} " CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
            <Label Text="{Binding Quantity}"
            TextColor="#f35e20" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Quantity}"
            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
            TextColor="#503026" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

[image]

I have upload [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/XamarinRefreshTest.git) to github. Please refer to.

Comment: I had to keep the Grid because I have much more columns than just 2 values.  But your solution to surround with a StackLayout (vertical orientation) fixed my problem.  Thanks a lot!